# Uploading files via email to Windows Azure

Tags: .net, asp.net, azure

I'm thinking of allowing users to upload files via email to an app on Windows Azure. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found out that this is possible by running your SMTP server on a worker role. You can specify an InputEndpoint on port 25 on the worker role. For more details, have a look at http://microsoftpdc.com/Sessions/SVC16

Answer (score 3):

I would run a mail server outside of Azure and then have your Azure application retrieve messages via POP.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Azure cannot receive any emails nor can you host an email server on Azure. You can host an emailserver yourself and automatically upload the attachments of a received email to Azure.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought. Was wondering if the SMTP port is closed and if there are other ways to do this, e.g. other Azure Services.

Comment: All ports are closed except port 80.

Answer (score 0):

We are doing the exact same thing also, uploading files via email and for the front-end using Azure. The problem now is that Azure does not support smtp server.

What we do is that we host our own exchange server, and write an interceptor(SmtpReceiveAgent) to process the incoming messages. If you found other solutions please let me know.

Thanks!